# replace an iptables rule without giving a rule number

Tags: iptables

Is it somehow possible to replace an `iptables` rule without giving a rule number or insert/append a rule by overwriting the existing rule if the rule added is identical to one already in the chain? The reason I ask is that I have a script which automatically adds `iptables` rules and there can be a case where rule added is identical to one already in the chain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a close enough way to do what you're asking. `iptables` has the option [`-C/--check`](https://manpages.debian.org/iptables/iptables.8#OPTIONS):

> **-C, --check** chain rule-specification
>
> Check whether a rule matching the specification does exist in the selected chain. This command uses the same logic as **-D** to find a
>   matching entry, but does not alter the existing iptables configuration
>   and uses its exit code to indicate success or failure.

So if for example you have some automatic script trying to do something like this:

```
iptables -I FORWARD -s 10.0.3.0/24 -d 10.0.4.0/24 -j ACCEPT
```

and you don't want to pollute your rules, you can do this instead:

```
iptables -C FORWARD -s 10.0.3.0/24 -d 10.0.4.0/24 -j ACCEPT || \
    iptables -I FORWARD -s 10.0.3.0/24 -d 10.0.4.0/24 -j ACCEPT
```

which will check if the rule exists. If it returns true, nothing happens, if it returns false the shell will execute the 2nd `iptables` rule. If this was always done like this, you idempotently get once and only once this rule (but see later about ordering). You could have used `-A` but `-I` is more likely to help.

If the position of the rule does matter but you don't know exactly where it currently is due to other changes, you should use an user defined chain to do this operation. That way the rule will always be called at the position of the jump:

```
iptables -N mychain
iptables -A FORWARD -m comment --comment first_rule
iptables -A FORWARD -m comment --comment initially_second -j mychain

iptables -C mychain -s 10.0.3.0/24 -d 10.0.4.0/24 -j ACCEPT || \
    iptables -A mychain -s 10.0.3.0/24 -d 10.0.4.0/24 -j ACCEPT
```

That way if there was an exception inserted before at some time:

```
iptables -I FORWARD 2 -s 10.0.3.10 -d 10.0.4.20 -m comment --comment now_second -j DROP
```

your script will not reinsert the rule before this exception and cancel it.

Comment: Using the `-C` switch does the job but that will be too much writing (basically writing the same command twice). Is there a more compact way to do the same ?

Comment: @W.M. You can factorize the use with shell scripting and an adequate function, beware of handling of spaces, quotes and special characters in such case.

Comment: @W.M. or, if the task at hand allows it, you can separate data (IP addresses) from code (rules) by using the companion ipset facility, or switch to nftables and use sets for the same. Such sets, being sets, won't have duplicates so there's no need to do checks.